# Playing raw PCM with NAudio (outputs noise but opens fine in Audacity)

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio, pcm

I am using NAudio (1.7.1.17) WasapiLoopbackCapture which works fine and I can open the saved Raw PCM in Audacity with the following format:

[image: Raw PCM Format]

Calling code targeting .NET 4 x86. The file is a 10 second recording totalling [3,515,904 bytes].

**CAPTURE:**

```
var device = WasapiLoopbackCapture.GetDefaultLoopbackCaptureDevice();

using (var capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(device))
{
    capture.ShareMode = AudioClientShareMode.Shared;
    capture.DataAvailable += WasapiCapture_DataAvailable;
    capture.RecordingStopped += WasapiCapture_RecordingStopped;

    // Verified that [capture.WaveFormat] is [44.1KHz, 32 bit 2 ch].

    capture.StartRecording();
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    capture.StopRecording();
}

private void WasapiCapture_DataAvailable (object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    // Write [e.BytesRecorded] number of bytes from [e.Buffer] to a file.
}

private void WasapiCapture_RecordingStopped (object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    // Verified that e.Exception was null.
}
```

**PLAYBACK:**

```
var file = new FileInfo(/* Same file that was just recorded. */);

using (var stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    var waveOut = new WaveOut();
    var waveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 32, 2); // Same format.
    var rawSource = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, waveFormat);
    waveOut.Init(rawSource);
    waveOut.Play();
}
```

The playback code produces noise that is at most one second long. I double-checked the byte-order and everything looks good except for the size (which should ideally be [3,528,000 bytes]. I'm not sure if padding is the issue here I need to be able to stream this Raw PCM data without knowing the full size in advance.

But first things first. Any pointers on how to get NAudio to play this file would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `WaveFormat` encoding needs to be IEEE float not PCM (which it currently is)

```
WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100,2)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's been a while but I was wondering if there is a way to record directly as PCM. Had not heard of the IEEE Float format up until your answer. Is that possible with any of the drivers / protocols (WASAPI, ASIO, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

The Solution is to move waveOut.Play() to a separate thread.

Also, since you have a "using" statement in your code, the objects required for the playback are disposed before the playback completed.

For starters, I would do it like this:

```
public partial class PlayerForm: Form
{
    WaveOut waveOut;
    Thread t;
    FileStream stream;
    WaveFormat waveFormat;
    RawSourceWaveStream rawSource;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        waveOut = new WaveOut();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(@"<your file here>");

        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        waveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000,16,1); // Same format.
        rawSource = new NAudio.Wave.RawSourceWaveStream(stream, waveFormat);
         waveOut.Init(rawSource);

         t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Play));
            t.Start();
    }

    private void Play()
    {
        waveOut.Play();
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not final production quality code as it does not consider what happens when button is clicked twice.

Comment: Thanks. Although not the core problem, that was certainly a scoping issue as you pointed out.